# Atom gpp compiling error : Nodejs child_process.spawn whitespace in cwd

Tags: c++, node.js, atom-editor, spawn

I just installed the editor Atom and the package gpp https://github.com/livace/atom-gpp to compile and run c++. When i run i get an error saying there is no such file or directory.

I think this is because of the fact that there is a whitespace in my directory path. I checked the source code of the gpp plugin and found this:

```
const options = (file.path + ' -o ' + compiledPath + ' ' + atom.config.get('gpp.compilerOptions')).replace(/[\s{2,}]+/g, ' ').trim();

path.join(filePath.dir, filePath.name);

const child = child_process.spawn('g++', options.split(' '), {
  cwd: filePath.dir
});
```

I have never worked with nodeJs before, but i think that this causes the bug. Any idea how to make this work with a whitespace in the directory path (cwd)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. In index.js of the gpp plugin, change

```
const options = (file.path + ' -o ' + compiledPath + ' ' + atom.config.get('gpp.compilerOptions')).replace(/[\s{2,}]+/g, ' ').trim();

path.join(filePath.dir, filePath.name);
console.log(options.split(' '));
const child = child_process.spawn('g++', options.split(' '), {
  cwd: filePath.dir
});
```

To

```
  const options = atom.config.get('gpp.compilerOptions').replace(/[\s{2,}]+/g, ' ').trim();

  path.join(filePath.dir, filePath.name);
  var new_options = [file.path,'-o',compiledPath]
  if (options != ""){
    new_options = new_options.concat(options.split(' '));
  }
  const child = child_process.spawn('g++', new_options, {
    cwd: filePath.dir
  });
```

Comment: If someone has the same problem, i contacted the author and it is patched. Just update your plugin